# What is the proper way to get data from database in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

I have some simple react app with authorisation, which is done with - jwh tokens and Redux magic code, that I cannot understand to the point (and hope not to touch that technology if that is ever possible - really dislike it, too obfuscated and complex-to-write style for novice). But that's lyrics away.

So after login some token is saved somewhere, some magic happened, and this have two consequences: now I have my `user.id` in `props.user`, and may call api endpoints with axios, (normally unavailble without auth).

Now I have user login history table, and I want to display a data table associated with user on a page. Where should I fetch the database? Simpliest way I found up to date is to poll backend api (to poll mongoDb) in `componentWillMount()` method. Then I could have access to the data in `render()`, to display user table. Is that correct? Or am I forced to somehow "sync state" with a Redux? Or what? I am lost in paradigms..

---

PS. Polling that works, but if data is updated dynamically by another user I cannot see updates about that he was logged in (without refreshing page).

Comment: The idea is that you dispatch an `action` - which could do a fetch API call. This action is then handled by the appropriate reducer to ensure that the data is stored to the appropriate store. This action is indeed usually dispatched from the `componentDidMount`. I'd suggest you'd try to look past your aversion for Redux, and understand how it works. It would answer your question.

Comment: Also, if you are implementing your components correctly, they should be re-rendered once the props change. So if you are using some kind of `mapStateToProps`, React would know to re-render (without refreshing the page) when the data was updated (dynamically).

Comment: @nbokmans But I do not need any "action" like "register" or "change some backend state". I need a passive lookup, that does not modify any data. Why should I dispatch an "action", if I just want to "passively look"? I dont have an aversion, I just told that it is very obfuscated, even for experienced programmer to understand what is it for and how should it be used, without speding a years deep-studying it first. IMO, that's simply not "how transparent and convenient things are usually done"!

Comment: In that case yes, you can get by without using Redux as you want. Simply do your api fetch call in your componentDidMount, and save that data in your state (as per @Saraband's answer). However, this data is then lost when the component is unmounted (usually when you navigate away from the screen and are not using something like `react-navigation`'s `StackNavigator`). That's where Redux comes in handy: you can retain your data for future visits to this screen, so that the page is not empty (bad UX IMO). But I digress, that's just my 2 cents on the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to, if possible, make the basic logic without using Redux at first, it takes time for the paradigms to sink in - how and why to use them etc. Secondly `componentWillMount` is (will be) deprecated and it was never the place to put data requests but `componentDidMount` (as stated in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)).

The basic React way to do things is to call the request in `componentDidMount` and *then* put the response into the component state via `setState` which would cause a rerender with the new data. With Redux you do a similar thing, you *dispatch* the *action* in the same place, the action calls the request and *then* the response is put into the global state via a *reducer*. However for the component to update on a state change, it needs to be subscribed to that part of the state. The easiest way to do this is to wrap the component with the `connect` high order function from [react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux) and pass that part of the state as a prop to the component via the `mapStateToProps` object.

If all of this sounds like lot in comparison to just having the local component state, it is, and that's why I advise first try to implement the logic without Redux. These extra steps have their merit in large projects where it's beneficial to have a global state opposed to passing handlers all over the place and a large container component for the state, but it comes with a lot of boilerplate to get used to.

---

Now the second part of your problem is, if I'm not mistaken, updating the state when some other user updates the data somewhere else? That's a typical problem on the web and you won't get around it with React or Redux, because it has nothing to do with them but needing to constantly check for changes. Or in other words, you need the way for the server to notify your React app that the data has changed.

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

1. The quick and dirty solution where you start a [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)
   timer in your component to constantly send requests and update the
   state every **X** seconds (just don't forget to [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)
   before the component unmounts or it will continue to send request
   indefinite)
2. Use [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) to get notifications when the data is
   changed
3. Use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) or [socket.io](https://socket.io/) for the same functionality as
   server side events, or you can also move all your data
   communication to go through one of those services rather than
   standard HTTP requests

Comment: I found calling api in `componentWillMount` a bit better ("is going to mount"), in terms of that it often comes before `render()`, at least on dev machine. Do you confirm its more suitable place than `DidMount`? `SetInterval` is server-heavy. Server events is that i was asking for, but didnt knew how that was called. WebSockets - I have not so heavy-dynamics site to bother, but I really like that stuff.

Comment: You can find a good explanation for why to avoid it [in the blog post when WillMount deprecation was announced](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data). Long story short: if the render fires before the `setState` is over (which can happen), it won't rerender and you will have the component renderd in some state you never wanted it to be.

Comment: Furthermore, even if you manage to somehow block the render, if you have a long request you will be blocking the render for an extended period of time - in which case, from an UX perspective, it's better to have a loading screen that's rendered if the state has it's initial values, than a blank screen that the user will probably refresh and just keep calling the same request over and over again. Not to mention that a true blocking call would block some other events and your attempt at optimization could have the opposite effect.

Comment: Very funny, more like multi-threaded data race issues. However logically, you want to issue request as early as possible, and that's engine sync problem, whereas ideologacically everything just must be that way. `will mount`=`on create`, and `did mount` is a non existing event (in windows forms for example)

Comment: Well if you want that behaviour and you're using Redux for your state you can call the action that issues the request in "WillMount", and then let everything continue on as usual and the component will rerender when the state changes. However, as I've said, `WillMount` is being deprecated so it should be avoided in all new code in favour of putting all `onCreate` code into the component's constructor (which is always sync so you can't await the API call there).

Comment: The problem with something like `will mount`=`an blocking async on create` not being an option in the browser has to do with how browsers and JS in general work, you have a single thread to work in (unless you're using workers or something like that) and in that thread both React has to build and render its virtual DOM and then the browser has to render the physical DOM from the React's rendered virtual one, along with processing all of those HTTP requests which are always async AND the rest of the JS code - forcing all that code to run synchronously would be a disaster in performance.

Comment: In Windows Forms you have a single engine running everything that has access to multiple threads so it can happily run everything in the background until it's ready to send the "rendered" new screen to the main process and not block anything. Imagine running Windows Forms without Tasks or similar mechanisms that enable the use of multiple threads if possible and then having a long blocking network request before a new screen renders, how long would it take for Windows to put the "Not Responding" label on that app?

Comment: by `a blocking async on create` I meant to say blocking the render (blocking and async don't make much sense next to one another)

Comment: So `didMount` is a more like `onShow` event, called everytine it displayed, and will mount now moved to constructor and called only once. No, I am not trying to block render. Inside is promise-based axios `.then` stuff

Comment: I just pointed, that `willMount` is felt like "thing is about to be displayed, so issue an request" and didMount is a stub, to force developers to display something in absence of data. Normally everything must be done in will mount and render must correctly parse only completed fetches, which usually is done manually in desktop apps

Comment: Mount is called only once - right after the constructor. Mount basically means "hey React, put this object into your memory", everything after that is just updating that object and React rerendering it (note that there are ways how you can keep an object mounted without rendering anything). Unmount happens before the object is destroyed so you can view it as a Dispose or descructor method (more like dispose).

Comment: I disagree, i observe the behavior that my site calls "willMount" every time. I have `Provider>Router>..` then a bunch of routes, and a `/loginhistory` route among them. So React could create this component knowing bout it right from the App.js. But when i logout, then login, then visit this page again - i could see a entry added (if you insist that nothing is reloaded/recreated) - A entry list is just fetched via axios from backend in one place - that's `willMount` method of `loginhistory` component

Comment: Yes but in desktop apps users don't expect as nearly instant changes when they click something as they do with web apps. In a web app, when you click on a link either a change happens in the next 2-3 secs (at least some loading indicator or a blank page) or the user will click it again or refresh the page and lose all progres.

Comment: However if you really want this behaviour you can wrap your redirects with a function that will first await a request and then issue the redirect with the data saved in the global state or sent as a prop. But as I said, that's not how the web works or users expect it to work

Comment: Why not use React.js for your router web face? In a (mostly) gigabit LAN everything normally happens in under 10-30ms, and (have to be) almost indistinguishable from local machine Apps experience :) Although websockets are way better in this scenario.. Would you still recommend to issue websocket requests(subscribe for realtime graph..) in `didMount`?

Comment: Ah sorry, maybe I wan't clear with the whole mount and dismount thing. First, if you refresh the screen the virtual DOM is lost and React needs to build it again. Secondly, when a redirect happens the router component rerenders and the vitual DOM is changed because the router only renders one route, React in the process then dismounts the old object (component) along with its children and leaves it to the garbage collector to be destroyed, while mounting the new object (component) on that route - React does not memorize old "screens" in the background like desktop and mobile apps do.

Comment: You should start your own (mern) courses! Thanks, everything is clear now :)

Comment: Subscribing to an event is synchronous, so feel free put into the constructor - however in my experience it doesn't make much of a difference is it in the constructor or `did mount`, unless you're doing some kind of handshake or have a locking mechanism `on load` which are problems to troubleshoot in general.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help. :)

For courses and such I'm always a bit afraid of doing those because I don't know as much as it might seem here. I just had multiple experiences with mobile and desktop developers not understanding how the web works. Try to think of the web as having to update a structured text document (that's all the physical DOM is) on every change and React just being a tool that does that for you in a more elegant matter so you can build something more complex. Also, courses are often either too basic or became deprecated because JS libraries change at a very fast pace.

Comment: For the basics of Redux, Dan Abramov has a pretty good [course](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux). Other than that, read the docs of the libs you're using and you'll slowly get the hang of it by building stuff. If you're ever stuck on the Redux part, try implementing something without it and then slowly move that code into Redux. At the end of the day, Redux is just a global wrapper component that maintains your state and can be updated from any point of you're app (and then causes rerenders of any components that would normally rerender if a prop changed).

Comment: Sure thing, I've learned most of everything by myself, via trials-and-errors way. Now it comes for redux, and I stucked, cause its new way doin old. For example those multiple nesting arrows are real head wreckers: `export const registerUser = (user, history) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/api/users/register', user).then(res => history.push('/login')).catch(err => {
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_ERRORS,
                    payload: err.response.data
                });
            });
}` a function that returns a function that.. THAT IS NOT HOW U PROGRAM)))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187436/discussion-between-xakepp35-and-5ar).

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do it is - like you said - to fetch your data in the `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount` hook of your component.

Note that because you called your API in one of those hooks doesn't mean that your data will be accessible instantly in the first call of your render function. Your API call is probably asynchronous and your component will not wait its execution to render.

So you need to have some kind of placeholder for your data being fetched, for example you can do this like that (Without redux, only storing your data in your component state):

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isFetchingData: false,
      data: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.setState({ isFetchingData: true });
    apiCall().then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        isFetchingData: true,
        data
      });
    });
  }

  render () {
    if (!this.state.data) {
      return <p>No data</p>;
    }

    if (!this.state.isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading data</p>;
    }

    // Render your component with data
  }
}
```

Comment: Like this, very transparent and good example to start! But how to handle dynamic updates, eg, if called `apiCall()` once, rendered my data, but then after couple of seconds someone updates my data in the backend - how could I know when to call `apiCall()` next time? Setting a timeout could be server-heavy..